# How to view all my posts and comments in chronological order

Tags: support

Given Stack Exchange stores everything in the database I would like to know whether there is a place where I can view all my posts and comments in chronological order.

That way I can see what I was thinking on any given day and how one thought led to another (maybe this should be found at the Activity tab in the UI).

Comment: Toronto? What Toronto? You mean you want to know *where you have been* when posting, based on your IP?

Comment: Yes posting (Dot or italics.

Comment: *Sigh*. I give up.

Comment: Anyway, to answer the question in the title, [here you go](http://stackexchange.com/users/6423842/jack-maddington?tab=activity).

Comment: @ShadowWizard autocorrect for 'into one'??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ which part? "Toronto" or "Dot or italics"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard lol, Toronto (in case that wasn't a joke :P)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ photo courtesy (auto correct for "of course" ;))

Comment: Yup, looks like a severe case of rogue autocorrect without OP bothering to check or fix.

Comment: It was, a Joke,.,,,*,.,:,;*, but my problem is that I caann only add text. Can't express myself ?;-(|! (!) BIG-VOID-HERE-Q?

Comment: umm... so don't post while your mobile device is not working properly? It's like driving in a car with a bad wheel - you'll just bump into walls and other cars. Same here, you'll just get your questions downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407750/all-answer-questions-comments-over-time?accountid=6423842) does that. To run the query you need your accountid which you can find in the url if you visit your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/6423842/jack-maddington)

```sql
---- accountid: Account on stackexchange.com! "In the url on stackexchange.com"

-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
       
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO

declare @accountid int = ##accountid:int##  -- 93484

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_posts ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , id int
                            , type nvarchar(1)
                            , creationdate datetime
                            , title nvarchar(250));
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_posts 
               select @url
     , p.id as id
     , case 
       when posttypeid = 1 then ''Q''
       when posttypeid = 2 then ''A''
       end as type
     , p.creationdate
     , title
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where u.accountid = ' + cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + '
union
select @url
     , c.id
     , ''C''
     , c.creationdate
     , substring([text],1,250)
from comments c
inner join users u on u.id = c.userid
where u.accountid = ' + cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + ';'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , type
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + case when type ='C' 
            then '/posts/comments/'
            else '/q/'
       end
     + cast(id as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + title as link
     , creationdate
from #all_posts
order by creationdate 

drop table #all_posts

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl
```

The result for running this query for your account id gives the following result at time of posting. Do notice that SEDE is only refreshed once a week, in the weekend, so your most recent posts might not be in this query yet.

[image: all posts and comments over time]

Comment: Nice, but isn't it exactly what the [network profile activity tab](http://stackexchange.com/users/6423842/jack-maddington?tab=activity) is doing?

Comment: probably yes, next time please tell me before I write the query @ShadowWizard :D

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your excellent answer. Too bad this cannot run this directly from the profile, a bit cumbersome to cut two items on a mobile phone (eg. Android), and cut and paste both the query and the user id on a mobile phone. Any idea how to do this without entering the data into a desktop computer?

Comment: @Jack you can read the comments I wrote, both here and on your question.